# boost::property_tree::json_parser and two-byte wide characters

Tags: c++, boost, unicode, boost-propertytree

## Introduction

```
std::string text = "á";
```

"á" is two-byte character (assuming a UTF-8 encoding).
So following line prints 2.

```
std::cout << text.size() << "\n";
```

But `std::cout` still prints text correctly.

```
std::cout << text << "\n";
```

## My problem

I pass `text` to `boost::property_tree::ptree` and then to `write_json`

```
boost::property_tree::ptree root;
root.put<std::string>("text", text);

std::stringstream ss;
boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(ss, root);
std::cout << ss.str() << "\n";
```

The result is

```
{
    "text": "\u00C3\u00A1"
}
```

text is equal to "Ã¡" which is different than "á".

Is is possible to fix this problem without switching to `std::wstring`? Is it possible that changing library (`boost::property_tree::ptree`) can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found some solutions.
In general you needs to specify `boost::property_tree::json_parser::create_escapes` template for `[Ch=Char]`, to provide your "special occasion bug free escaping".

JSON standard assume that all string are UTF-16 encoded with "\uXXXX" escaping, but some library support UTF-8 encoding with "\xXX" escaping. If JSON file can be encoded in UTF-8, you may pass all character higher than 0x7F, witch was intended for original function.

I put this code before using `boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json`. It comes from `boost_1_49_0/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_write.hpp`:

```
namespace boost { namespace property_tree { namespace json_parser
{
    // Create necessary escape sequences from illegal characters
    template<>
    std::basic_string<char> create_escapes(const std::basic_string<char> &s)
    {
        std::basic_string<char> result;
        std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator b = s.begin();
        std::basic_string<char>::const_iterator e = s.end();
        while (b != e)
        {
            // This assumes an ASCII superset. But so does everything in PTree.
            // We escape everything outside ASCII, because this code can't
            // handle high unicode characters.
            if (*b == 0x20 || *b == 0x21 || (*b >= 0x23 && *b <= 0x2E) ||
                (*b >= 0x30 && *b <= 0x5B) || (*b >= 0x5D && *b <= 0xFF)  //it fails here because char are signed
                || (*b >= -0x80 && *b < 0 ) ) // this will pass UTF-8 signed chars
                result += *b;
            else if (*b == char('\b')) result += char('\\'), result += char('b');
            else if (*b == char('\f')) result += char('\\'), result += char('f');
            else if (*b == char('\n')) result += char('\\'), result += char('n');
            else if (*b == char('\r')) result += char('\\'), result += char('r');
            else if (*b == char('/')) result += char('\\'), result += char('/');
            else if (*b == char('"'))  result += char('\\'), result += char('"');
            else if (*b == char('\\')) result += char('\\'), result += char('\\');
            else
            {
                const char *hexdigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
                typedef make_unsigned<char>::type UCh;
                unsigned long u = (std::min)(static_cast<unsigned long>(
                                                 static_cast<UCh>(*b)),
                                             0xFFFFul);
                int d1 = u / 4096; u -= d1 * 4096;
                int d2 = u / 256; u -= d2 * 256;
                int d3 = u / 16; u -= d3 * 16;
                int d4 = u;
                result += char('\\'); result += char('u');
                result += char(hexdigits[d1]); result += char(hexdigits[d2]);
                result += char(hexdigits[d3]); result += char(hexdigits[d4]);
            }
            ++b;
        }
        return result;
    }
} } }
```

And the output I get:

```
{
    "text": "aáb"
}
```

Also the function `boost::property_tree::json_parser::a_unicode` have similar problems with reading escaped unicode characters to signed chars.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nice find with `boost::property_tree::json_parser::create_escapes`. Your solution is definitely an improvement. But I don't think it works for whole UTF-8 charset;/. Am I right ?

Comment: All bytes that code Unicode character over 0x7F are above 0x7F ( below 0 for signed char ), so this function pass through UTF-8 correctly. Some unicode characters may not be printable of course, and some UTF-8 sequence must never appear.

Comment: The JSON standard does not make any assumptions about encoding.  Per RFC 46273.  Encoding

   JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
   UTF-8.

   Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII
   characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
   stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
   at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.

           00 00 00 xx  UTF-32BE
           00 xx 00 xx  UTF-16BE
           xx 00 00 00  UTF-32LE
           xx 00 xx 00  UTF-16LE
           xx xx xx xx  UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Boost fixed it on 1.59 version. And you need careful if you want to upgrade version. You can check what changed from below.
https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_59_0.html

Answer (score -1):

Support above Basic Multilingual Plane:

```
    template<class Ch>
std::basic_string<Ch> create_escapes(const std::basic_string<Ch> &s)
{
    std::basic_string<Ch> result;
    typename std::basic_string<Ch>::const_iterator b = s.begin();
    typename std::basic_string<Ch>::const_iterator e = s.end();
    while (b != e)
    {
        if (*b == 0x20 || *b == 0x21 || (*b >= 0x23 && *b <= 0x2E) ||
            (*b >= 0x30 && *b <= 0x5B) || (*b >= 0x5D && *b <= 0x80))
            result += *b;
        else if (*b == Ch('\b')) result += Ch('\\'), result += Ch('b');
        else if (*b == Ch('\f')) result += Ch('\\'), result += Ch('f');
        else if (*b == Ch('\n')) result += Ch('\\'), result += Ch('n');
        else if (*b == Ch('\r')) result += Ch('\\'), result += Ch('r');
        else if (*b == Ch('/')) result += Ch('\\'), result += Ch('/');
        else if (*b == Ch('"'))  result += Ch('\\'), result += Ch('"');
        else if (*b == Ch('\\')) result += Ch('\\'), result += Ch('\\');
        else
        {
            const char * hexdigits = "0123456789ABCDEF";

            typedef typename make_unsigned<Ch>::type UCh;
            unsigned long u = static_cast<unsigned long>(static_cast<UCh>(*b));

            if (u <= 0xFFFF)
            {            
                int d1 = u / 4096; u -= d1 * 4096;
                int d2 = u / 256; u -= d2 * 256;
                int d3 = u / 16; u -= d3 * 16;
                int d4 = u;

                result += Ch('\\'); result += Ch('u');
                result += Ch(hexdigits[d1]); result += Ch(hexdigits[d2]);
                result += Ch(hexdigits[d3]); result += Ch(hexdigits[d4]);
            }
            else
            {
                u = (((static_cast<unsigned long>(static_cast<UCh>(*b)) - 0x10000) >> 10) & 0x3ff) + 0xd800;

                int d1 = u / 4096; u -= d1 * 4096;
                int d2 = u / 256; u -= d2 * 256;
                int d3 = u / 16; u -= d3 * 16;
                int d4 = u;

                result += Ch('\\'); result += Ch('u');
                result += Ch(hexdigits[d1]); result += Ch(hexdigits[d2]);
                result += Ch(hexdigits[d3]); result += Ch(hexdigits[d4]);

                u = ((static_cast<unsigned long>(static_cast<UCh>(*b)) - 0x10000) & 0x3ff) + 0xdc00;

                d1 = u / 4096; u -= d1 * 4096;
                d2 = u / 256; u -= d2 * 256;
                d3 = u / 16; u -= d3 * 16;
                d4 = u;

                result += Ch('\\'); result += Ch('u');
                result += Ch(hexdigits[d1]); result += Ch(hexdigits[d2]);
                result += Ch(hexdigits[d3]); result += Ch(hexdigits[d4]);
            }
        }
        ++b;
    }
    return result;
}
```