# How do you include a template in c++ code?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, include

I'm uncomfortable with some of the syntactical elements of C++, in particular regarding compilation and includes.  I was trying to implement the solution listed in the following Q&A:

[boost::property_tree::json_parser and two-byte wide characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260688/boostproperty-treejson-parser-and-two-byte-wide-characters/17493712#17493712)

In doing so, pasted the suggested template code in an .h file that is being included by my .cpp file.  I also added the following to the top of my .cpp, thinking I needed to reference what I'm overriding:

```
#include "boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_write.hpp"
```

I am getting the following compilation error:

```
Error   11  error C2912: explicit specialization; 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>   boost::property_tree::json_parser::create_escapes(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &)' is not a specialization of a function template   d:\abr.trunk\e1\livesdencoder\web\encodingservice\h264presentation.h    151
```

What am I doing wrong to get this override of create_escapes registered for use?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what happens if you don't include that file?

Comment: I get the same error with or without that include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all in the same .hpp file... remember: templates are like macros...
good luck!

Comment: I don't want to edit the boost .hpp file.  Do you mean that I should put the template definition in my own .cpp file where I am calling the write_xml function?  If I do that, do I need to add something also to my .h file?

Comment: Good news... I pasted the template into the .cpp file, and it worked.  I guess the .h file was the wrong place to put it.  Thanks to everyone for the help.